# How can I prevent a daemon started over SSH from terminating at logout?

Tags: linux, ssh, daemon

EDIT this is fixed. See my answer below.

---

I have a headless server running transmission-daemon on Angstrom Linux. I am able to SSH into the machine and invoke transmission-daemon via [this init script](https://trac.transmissionbt.com/wiki/Scripts/initd); however, the process terminates as soon as I log out.

The command issued in the script is:

```
start-stop-daemon --chuid transmission --start --pidfile /var/run/transmission-daemon.pid --make-pidfile --exec /usr/local/bin/transmission-daemon --background -- -f
```

After starting the daemon via `# /etc/init.d/transmission-daemon start`, I can verify using `ps` that the process is owned by the user `transmission` (which is not the user I am logging in as via SSH).

I've tried every variation of the above command that I am aware of, including:

- With and without the `--background` option for start-stop-daemon
- Appending `> /dev/null 2>&1 &` to the start-stop-daemon command ([source](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/33815/why-jobs-arent-killed-at-logout-when-executed-with-dev-null-21) -- although there seems to be mixed results in that thread as to whether this is the right approach)
- Appending `> /dev/null 2>&1 & </dev/null &` ([source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1495656/3814313))
- Adding `&` to the end of the command
- Using `nohup`

None of these seems to work -- the result is always the same: the process exits immediately after I close the SSH session.

What can/should I do to keep the daemon running after I disconnect the SSH session?

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried using GNU Screen?

It allows you to keep your session open even if you disconnect (but not if you exit).

It's a simple case of:

```
apt-get install screen
```

or

```
yum install screen
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. To clarify, this init script was previously working correctly. I would really prefer to get the init script working again if possible.

Answer (score 2):

Since I cannot leave comments yet :), here is a good site that explains some functions of Screen, http://www.tecmint.com/screen-command-examples-to-manage-linux-terminals/

I use screens all the time, to do exactly what you are talking about. You open a screen, in the terminal, do what you need to do, then you can log off and your process will still be running.

Answer (score 2):

```
sudo loginctl enable-linger your_user 
# This allows users who are not logged in to run long-running
# service after ssh session ends
```

Answer (score 0):

This is now resolved. Here's the background: at some point prior to running into this problem, something happened to my $PATH (I don't recall what) and the location where transmission-daemon lived (`/sbin`) was removed. Under the mistaken impression that transmission-daemon was no longer present on the system, I installed again from an ipk. This is the state the system was in when I initially asked this question.

I don't know why it made a difference, but once I corrected my $PATH and started running transmission-daemon installed at /sbin, everything worked again. The daemon keeps running after I log out.